# Slow JVM on new Windows 10 workstation

Tags: java, jvm

I built a new workstation based on an intel 7820x processor (8 core, X-299). Compared to my old machine (6-core 3.5 Ghz Xeon MacPro, 2013), the single core performance is about 40% faster, and the multi-core performance is about 100% faster.

There is one exception: Java performance under Windows 10 (Home), which is about 10% slower than the old machine under OSX. I tried many options, from different versions of JVM 8 (unfortunately JVM 7 and 9 are no options for me) to playing with the new Turbo Boost technology, to various JVM arguments (XMX, aggressiveopts, ...) to even giving the Linux Subsystem for Windows a try.

When I run my programs on the same machine on a JVM under Linux (Ubuntu), the performance is as expected (between 40% - 100% faster).

Does anybody have a clue what is going on? I suspect that I am missing certain flags/arguments for the JVM, or perhaps hitting a bug, but I seem to have run out of options.

My JVM workload focuses on single core activities, with limited multicore activities. Memory usage is low to moderate (typical web server), hardly any disk activity is involved.

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried a 32 bit version of Java 8 ? Also, how are you measuring performance ?

Comment: Partially some proprietary number crunching algorithms, partially the performance of the web server.

Comment: Windows offers a lot of things that are 'touching' your processes, ofc for better user experience. You could always disable the antivirus and disable the caching for the `runtime` directories. Also there are other settings,like run as admin(!), but because you are running on a Home version you need to check optimizations specifically. Also as asked above , are you using a 32 or 64 bit Client/Server VM? Also are you invoking the *webserver* using the jre or the jdk path? The *linux* VM , is it an oracle-jdk? or you are comparing also the oracle-jdk with the bundled osx/linux open-jdk?

Answer (score 0):

Would suspect the L3 cache size difference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was also thinking in such a direction. However, that doesn't explain why the performance of the JVM in Linux is so stellar on exactly the same machine...

Comment: If you run a profiler you can compare. If the profiler shows nothing major then I would speculate timers (big change between OS). Then it'd be more difficult.